# Android Socket Programming Delay

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I have a client android app and a server program on PC. In client app, I start a new thread in onCreate() of my Activity. In that thread, there is an infinite loop which sends message to the server. But there is sometimes a delay of up to 5 seconds. Here is the code of client side:

**EDIT**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(ip, 1755);
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while(true) {
                if(socket != null) {
                    out.println(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Now the message is not being delivered.

Comment: Do you really want to create the socket in a loop. Why not creating once then send in a loop  then close it ?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @Krish Yes, I just checked your answer. Now I want to send messages whenever the user touches the screen. So, I'd just call sendMessage() inside onTouchEvent()?

Comment: Yes you can send message in onTouch().  But try to reduce the message count.

Comment: @Krish I used your code in my Java project. It works fine if I have to send a single message. But when I try sendMessage inside an infinite while loop, only the first message is sent. What mistake I'm making?

Comment: Did you got some Exception stack trace?

Comment: No exception shows up. The server side just receives the message of loop's first iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109377/discussion-between-krish-and-salman-younas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this code ,

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    /**
     * @author Krish
     */
    public class Client {


        public void connect() {
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }


        public void disconnect() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void sendMessage(String msg) {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);


           out.println(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private Socket socket;

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

        private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.15";


        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And also find optimization techniq

Comment: socket object might be null. Because it is not synchronized. So implement a callback for connection status and sendMessage after that.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: What was the issue that we discussed last time?

Comment: I was creating the socket again and again. And at server, I was closing the connection after first iteration.

Comment: Use a callback for connection status . So that you can show offline and online status in view.

Comment: How to find connection status?

Comment: Simply use an  Interface and invoke it after creating a socket

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are creating infinite amount of sockets and sending. Rather than creating once and sending then closing or could be a network issue.

Comment: If I'm creating infinite amount of sockets, I'm also closing them. So what's the issue?

Comment: @SalmanYounas The issue is that you are doing it the hard way, wasting resources and network traffic.

Comment: @SalmanYounas Do you really want to do like this ? Could implement in some other way. Rather than creating infinite amount of sockets !!